# Iterate on Table Contents and selectively Insert/Update Records

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, sql-update, sql-insert

this is my first question here and my problem is:
i have a table in database from 8 columns (expiration_date , company , items , type , measure , amount ,box and quantity )
and in my program i have the same 8 columns i want to make a loop on table rows and update ( amount , box and quantity) if (expiration_date , company , items , type and measure ) are already exist before else insert a new row. 
this is the code but it's not working

[image]

```
try {
 String sel = "select * from DATA ";
 PreparedStatement stt = con.prepareStatement(sel);
 ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()){
              int row = tbl.getRowCount(); 
       for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       String dat       = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 0);
       String company   = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 1);
       String item      = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 2);
       String type      = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 3);
       String measure   = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 4);
       float box        = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 5);
       float amount     = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 6);
       float quantity   = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 7);
String up = "update DATA set BOX= BOX +? , AMOUNT =AMOUNT +? ,QUANTITY =QUANTITY +? WHERE                                  EXPIRATION_DATE='"+dat+"' and COMPANY='"+company+"' and ITEMS='"+item+"' and TYPEE='"+type+"' and     MEASURE='"+measure+"' ";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(up);
        st.setObject(1, box );
        st.setObject(2, amount);
        st.setObject(3, quantity);
        st.executeUpdate();
     }
     }else{
               int row = tbl.getRowCount(); 
         for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
         String dat       = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 0);
         String company   = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 1);
         String item      = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 2);
         String type      = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 3);
         String measure   = (String) tbl.getValueAt(i, 4);
         float box        = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 5);
         float amount     = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 6);
         float quantity   = (float) tbl.getValueAt(i, 7);
String in =  "insert into DATA (EXPIRATION_DATE, COMPANY, ITEMS, TYPEE, MEASURE,  BOX, AMOUNT, QUANTITY) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(in);
         stmt.setObject(1, dat);
         stmt.setObject(2, company);
         stmt.setObject (3, item );
         stmt.setObject (4, type);
         stmt.setObject (5, measure);
         stmt.setFloat (6, box);
         stmt.setFloat (7, amount);
         stmt.setFloat (8, quantity);
         stmt.executeUpdate(); 

              }
              }

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

      }
      }
```

[left pic for a program , right window for database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CQdz.jpg)

Comment: Not working in what way? Can you show us some sample input, the desired output, and the actual output?

Comment: i updated post by add picture of database and program.  the problem is there is not any action happen in database

Comment: I don't see you committing the transaction anywhere. Try putting `con.commit()` at the end of your method.

Comment: i put it but also there is not any action :(

Comment: i try this but it only insert not update :

Comment: `String sel = "select * from DATA EXPIRATION_DATE='"+dat+"' and COMPANY='"+company+"' and ITEMS='"+item+"' and TYPEE='"+type+"' and MEASURE='"+measure+'";

ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sel);`